# WPF DataGrid match all columns total width

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

My DataGrid is bound to a collection which can not change in run-time.
I wanted to ensure that when resizing the DataGrid columns the total width of the columns won't be
longer than the DataGrid width, so that no column will disappear and no horizontal scroll will appear, never find an answer to that.
So I wanted to no if there is a way that i can bind my DataGrid width to the total width of his columns so i can make the columns unresizeable and still have the columns width to "Auto" so no data will be missing while the columns is not resizeable?
Or the first option which i didn't find - limit the resize of the columns so their total width wont be longer?
Thank's a lot and please no Code-Behind soluton.

Comment: HorizontalScrollBar visible and CanUserResizeColumns did not do it?

Comment: You can also limit the resize of the columns by setting the column's MaxWidth property..

Comment: I dont want that information from specific column will disappear if the column size is too short and there is no resize option. Setting the max width of the column to specific length will cause the same problem, Is there any way I can do it with binding?

Comment: Sounds like you need a custom panel with a "smarter" layout. Why not just do what Blam suggested and put a scrollviewer around the entire thing. That way if the columns do go off the edge, a horizontal scrollbar will appear.